# Integral over a Hypercube

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

Let $C_R$ be a hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of  side length $2R$ and $B_R$ a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of radius $R$.

I know I can say that

$$\int_{B_R}f(x)\,dx \sim \int_{C_R} f(x)\,dx $$

Could anyone tell me how this can be made rigorous ?

Comment: I guess $\sim$ means "equivalent when $R\to\infty$" and $f$ is probably in $L^1(\Bbb R^n)$. Right?

Comment: If $A\lesssim B$ and $B \lesssim A$, the $A \sim B$.

Comment: The question is still unclear. What is $f$ ? You can't choose any hypercubes or ball too.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : If $f$ is a positive valued (locally) integrable function over $\Bbb R^n$, you have :

$$\int_{C_{R'}} f(x)dx\leq \int_{B_R} f(x)dx \leq \int_{C_R} f(x)dx$$

for all $R>0$ and $R'=\dfrac{R}{\sqrt{n}}$ (Note : I assumed that $C_R$, $C_{R'}$ and $B_R$ are centered at $0$)